# Cannot use RVM commands even after modifying .bash_profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I am a newbie RoR developer (and pretty newbie for programming in general). I followed the installation instructions on http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ to a T. I added...

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

...to my .profile and .bash_profile (at the very end) and yet I still cannot load RVM as a function. Note that I am getting -bash: ??: command not found" in Terminal.

Comment: What's the output for `ls $HOME/.rvm/scripts/`

Comment: alias   hash   patches
aliases   help   patchsets
array   hook   repair
base   info   rtfm
cd   initialize  rubygems
cleanup   install   rvm
cli   irbrc   rvm-install
color   irbrc.rb  selector
completion  list   set
current   log   snapshot
db   maglev   tools
default   manage   update
disk-usage  match   upgrade
docs   md5   utility
env   migrate   version
environment-convertor monitor   wrapper
fetch   notes   zsh
gemsets   override_gem
get   package